# logo in the middle of the two sections

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I don't want the image / logo to belong to a certain section, but rather to place it in the middle of the two sections, how can I do that?

```
    <body>
   
<section class="parent" style="height: 400px; background-color: blue">
   <div class="boxparent" style=" top: 10px;">
   </div>
</section>



<img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100.jpg/666/fff/000" style="position: absolute;background-color: #254543;z-index: 1;  left: 25%; "> 


<section class="parent" style="height: 400px; background-color: yellow;">
   <div class="boxparent">
      
   </div>
   
</section>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more accurate method to bring it to the exact center. Wrap both of your parent sections inside a wrapper so that the absolute image can be relative to the wrapper. This fixes the image to be inside the wrapper always. Then for the `img` you can use `calc` to calculate the `left` and `top` positions of the image. With this, the image will be at the 50% distance from both top and left to align it to center. `- 50px` is here because the width of the given image is `100x100` which means you need to deduct `50px` from both top and left to align it to the exact center.

Checkout the snippet below.

```css
.parent-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;  
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
}
.parent-a {
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: blue;
}
.parent-b {
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>   
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <section class="parent-a"></section>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100.jpg/666/fff/000"> 
    <section class="parent-b"></section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want vertically center of both section

```
top: 350px; // Since 400px is height of first section and 100px of image (400 - 50)px
```

if you also want horizontally and vertically center of both section

```
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="parent" style="height: 400px; background-color: blue">
  <div class="boxparent" style=" top: 10px;">
  </div>
</section>



<img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100.jpg/666/fff/000" style="position: absolute;background-color: #254543;z-index: 1;">


<section class="parent" style="height: 400px; background-color: yellow;">
  <div class="boxparent">

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thankxxxx very much

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place your image in upper section then apply just few `css` styles to to your image. I recommend to use `external stylesheet` for styling. However you are using `inline styles` then do it as follows;

```
<body>
<section class="parent" style="height: 400px; background-color: blue">
    <div class="boxparent" style=" top: 10px;">
    </div>
    <img src="https://place-hold.it/100x100.jpg/666/fff/000" style="background-color: #254543; position: relative;top: 350px;left: 45%;">
</section>

<section class="parent" style="height: 400px; background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="boxparent">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Never ever use inline css. Never. It's against W3 standards. The only exception is if the css styling is done using javascripts dynamically which the search engines do not tend to pick up as it occurs only when a javascript event is triggered.